# StackTrace behavior in case of rethrow exception c#

Tags: c#, try-catch, stack-trace, throw

As i already now, to keep the original **`stackTrace`** we should be avoiding using `throw` caught exception, instead, we should just use `throw` `clause` that in fact `rethrow` the exception.

The thing is that a few days age in an interview i was given a code to predict the `stacktrace` of final result:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ReThrowException(); // line 17
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception:");
            Console.WriteLine(x.StackTrace); //line 22
        }
    }

    private static void ReThrowException()
    {
        try
        {
            DivByZero(); 
        }
        catch
        {
            throw; //line 34
        }
    }

    private static void DivByZero()
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 1 / x; //line 41
    }
}
```

Exception occurs in `line 41` and in line 34 it just `rethrow` exception by keeping the original `stackTrace`.

My answer was:

> it just should be pointing to the `line 41`where exception actually
> occurred for the first time and nowhere `stackTrace` is overwriting in
> the code.

But the true answer was as follows:

```
Exception:
   at TestConsole.Program.DivByZero() in C:...\Projects\TestConsole\TestConsole\Program.cs:line 41
   at TestConsole.Program.ReThrowException() in C:...\Projects\TestConsole\TestConsole\Program.cs:line 34
   at TestConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:...\Projects\TestConsole\TestConsole\Program.cs:line 17
```

Now two questions come to my mind:

1.Why `stackTrace` is adding sources for lines `17,34`?
2.What should i do in the code to just `stackTrace` point to the `line 41` and remove other sources?

Comment: It's not showing you "other sources". It's a **stack** trace: it shows the call stack at the point that the exception was thrown. There may be many places that `DivByZero` is called from, and the stack trace shows which method exactly called it, and which method called that one, etc, right the way back up to your application's entry point (or thread handler, if it's on a background thread, etc). It's saying "Main called ReThrowException on line 17; ReThrowException called DivByZero on line 34 (except it hits the 'throw' point, not the original method call); DivByZero hit a problem on line 41".

Comment: you are right but when it points to line 34, it seems that i am using throw ex instead of throw clause.

Comment: No. If you used `throw ex;`, you'd lose the part of the stack trace which points to line 41 in `DivByZero`. `throw ex;` will completely remove the stack trace that's been recorded so far, and start again

Comment: yes,i lose original in this case, but it acting like i am throwing exception in the line 34.

Comment: No it is not -- you're reading it wrong. Look at the first entry to see where the exception was thrown. The rest of the entries show the points in code that your exception "hit" until it was finally caught and printed. The stack trace does not show all the points in code which threw the exception: it shows all of the points that the exception passed through as it bubbled up through your code.

Comment: `The thing is that a few days age in an interview i was given a code to predict the stacktrace of final result:` What a silly interview question. Particularly since stack traces for exceptions differ between .NET versions (I don't know if _this specific_ one will, but they do in some scenarios for sure).

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Why stackTrace is adding sources for lines 17,34?

It's not other `sources`, it's `stack` trace that shows the trace that leads to exception.
As the name `StackTrace` implies, it is not a single point, likewise it is a `path`.

> 2.What should I do in the code to just stackTrace point to the line 41 and remove other sources?

You cant, because your question comes from an misunderstanding regarding existence of stackTrace.

Answer (score -1):

"What should i do in the code to just stackTrace point to the line 41 and remove other sources?"

Don't catch it on line 34?

You should only catch an exception you know how to handle.   If you ever `catch()` or `catch(Exception)` then you are probably wrong (unless it's for logging and you rethrow).

Remember, exceptions are 'expensive'.   You should try and avoid them.  Dividing by zero is each to stop, and if it's 'normal' for your code to have a zero divisor, then that's not an exception and should be trapped with an `if`.

Comment: The stack trace will still have an entry for `ReThrowException` in that case, it's just that it will show line 30 instead of line 34 for that entry